# How to read value in textbox and add some extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a website which contains lot of static HTML pages (eg:1.html,2.html,3.html..... and so on). I have a textbox in each page when an user enter certain page number in this textbox they must redirect to that particular page. Suppose an user enter number 13 in the textbox and press enter it must redirect to 13.html.

P.S : Suggest with the combination of HTML + JS or anything frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $('#textboxid').change(function(){ document.location.href = $(this).val()+'.html';})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, you will have to change the selector to match your input:

```
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        location.href = this.value + ".html";
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ahW62/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        location.href = $('#textboxid').val()+ ".html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="txt" />
 <input type="button" onclick="redirect()" value="redirect" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function redirect() {
         var url = document.getElementById("txt").value;
         window.location.href = url + "html";
      }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```